# Shell script to grep logs on different host and write the grepped output to a file on Host 1

Tags: shell

Shell script needs to

ssh to Host2 from Host1
cd /test/test1/log
grep logs.txt for string error
write the grepped output to a file
and move that file to Host1

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by specifying the `-f` option to `ssh`:

```
ssh user@host -f 'echo "this is a logfile">logfile.txt'
ssh user@host -f 'grep logfile logfile.txt' > locallogfile.txt
cat locallogfile.txt
```

An example using a different directory and `cd` changing directories to it:

```
ssh user@host -f 'mkdir -p foo/bar'
ssh user@host -f 'cd foo/bar ; echo "this is a logfile">logfile.txt'
ssh user@host -f 'cd foo/bar ; echo "this is a logfile">logfile.txt'
ssh user@host -f 'cd foo/bar ; grep logfile logfile.txt' > locallogfile.txt
cat locallogfile.txt
```